# How to use existing Intellij projects as a I move forward with SBT?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

Novice SBT question - Now that I've started with some basic SBT tutorials, I'd like to start using SBT build files (within Intellij) a lot more often. However, there's a couple of problems with this :

1) Existing projects that I currently publish to a jar, and later import into other projects... how do I publish this jar file to my local repository? SBT publish-local doesn't seem to fit my situation, because the project was made in Intellij and is not (yet) an SBT project.

2) Suppose I do convert the project to an SBT build setup (and then import it into Intellij).. how do I configure Intellij to to publish-local (update) each time I build the project? I do not see many configurable settings around SBT within the new Intellij SBT support.

Using Intellij 13 and SBT 0.13.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For publishing, you simply use the [*publish* action](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Detailed-Topics/Publishing.html):

*To specify the repository, assign a repository to publishTo and optionally set the publishing style. For example, to upload to Nexus:*

```
publishTo := Some("Sonatype Snapshots Nexus" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots")
```

As for your second question, despite being a JetBrains fanboy, I have found SBT integration quite disappointing. For one thing, as the JetBrains documentation states itself, you need two plugins: [their plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5007?pr=idea) and [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea). You use *sbt-idea* to synchronize the IDEA module structure with the SBT build, and you use JetBrains' *idea-sbt-plugin* to execute SBT tasks in the "Before Launch" action in Run Configurations.

It sounds like you want to do an "install" on every build, so "Before Launch" action support isn't useful. I would suggest writing your own custom SBT task to install on build and using the [Command Line Tools Console](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/running-command-line-tool-commands.html) to execute that task with SBT as if from the command line. I know; that indirection is annoying.

Bear in mind one more thing. I have found numerous bugs with *idea-sbt-plugin*. At least on Mac. JetBrains told me the next version will be much better, and you can see for yourself with the next EAP version.

I certainly welcome others who have managed to have more success than I have to chime in.

Comment: Thanks this is great info! Im still not entirely sure how to publish-local , from within Intellij..

Comment: The `publishM2` task publishes to the local Maven repo. The `publishLocal` task publishes to the local Ivy repo. As I said, if I were to execute either via IntelliJ, I would do it through the Command Line Tools plugin because I don't think the robust support is there for SBT. Again, this has just been my experience. If you or anyone else can get everything working great with the SBT plugin proper, please tweet me.

Answer (score 2):

to get you started up quickly on using SBT to drive Idea, have a look at my template project called [skeleton](https://github.com/fractal/skeleton/)

It supports most of the basic tasks you'd want to do.

To publish to your repository, use the [publish](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Detailed-Topics/Publishing.html) task.

hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll give your project a try!